# Assembly searchPath via %PATH% environment

Tags: c#, assemblies, environment

I am developing a project and want to seperate the shared assemblies form project folder

```
+ Program Files
    + My Company

       +Commons
          * Assembly1.dll
          * Assembly2.dll
          * Assembly3.dll
          * Assembly4.dll

       +Project1
          * MyProject1.exe
          * MyProject1.exe.config

       +Project2
          * MyProject2.exe
          * MyProject2.exe.config
```

trying to make projects load assemblies from "Commons" folder so i change the system %PATH% environment to search for DLLs.

```
%PATH% = c:\Program files\My Company\Commons;%PATH%
```

but they dont look up the Path environment (Monitoring with [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645))
Can anybody show me the way how to define search path for assemblies from %PATH% environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
var folders = path.Split(';');
foreach (var folder in folders)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.*"))
    {
        // found files
    }
}
```

Do the search in the`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to find the dlls when your application is starting. More information about the event here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx

Comment: Note that the path variable may contain nonexistent directories (e.g. if an application uninstalled without cleaning it up), so  you should check for that with Directory.Exists() before doing Directory.GetFiles().

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe dotNET relies on path environment variable when binding assemblies.

See http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/17/bindingpolicy.html for a dotNET binding policy.

Especially, you might find the  element useful here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: i ve already try to set privatePath to app.config, but the path should be under the project folder to search for. if i set it "../Commons", it doesnt look to upper folders. I want myapp to search DLLs via %PATH% environment. Thanks

Comment: I found that it's simple to keep private assemblies and GAC as the only paths that contain referenced assemblies.  There's little harm in keeping a couple of copies of referenced DLLs.  Benefit is that it's abundantly clear which assembly will be used by your app.